# Windows Forms: Set window icon in source code (not using the designer tool)

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, visual-studio, icons

I wrote a Windows Form from scratch, only in C# code, not using Visual Studio's form editor.

Now I want to set an icon to the window, so I added the `myapp.ico` file as a resource and wrote in the Form's constructor:

```
var resources = new System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager(typeof(MyForm));
Icon = ((System.Drawing.Icon)(resources.GetObject("myapp.Icon")));
```

I also set `myapp.ico` in the project's Properties>Application>Icon and manifest>Icon.

But the icon is not displayed, I get the default 3 squares icon: [image]

Answer (score 0):

Loading the icon from resources like this fixed the issue:

```
Icon = ((System.Drawing.Icon)(Properties.Resources.myapp));
```

(You first need to add the `myapp.ico` file as a resource to the project)

I am open to any better solution.